# Why can I not lineup my image with my text inside flex? (I did it before)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am re-creating Instagram login page. My issue is I need to lineup Facebook icon with "Log in with Facebook" text.

I created a main container for this section, then wrapped both Facebook icon and Facebook text with divs as well. Then I applied flex to the main container. While the icon and Facebook text are on the same line (via align-items), the icon is still not lined up with the text. I tried looking into margins, paddings etc. I can't' seem to figure out what I screwed up. I used this similar approach in a different project I was doing and everything lined up perfectly.

Thank you very much, I have been at it for 3 hours now.

Here is a codepen with all the code:

https://codepen.io/Yukzor/pen/BaYGpLK

```css
.fb a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #385185;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.facebook {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.facebookwhole {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebookwhole">
  <div class="fbpicture">
    <img class="facebook" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flawyersandsettlements.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F09%2Ffacebook-logo.png&f=1&nofb=1">
  </div>
  <div class="fb">
    <a href="www.facebook.com">Log in with Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .right-side img has margin-top: 15px;

Comment: Oh crap, you are right! Thank you.  I am still a little bit confused, how does .right-side img affect the .facebook image since it is under different class? I was targeting Instagram image with that selector. I can't figure out how it piggy backed onto the facebook  image. Iv been at it for like 5 hours straight, i think my brain stopped working and im starting miss simple things.

Comment: EDIT: Uh, i need a break. I see my css selector .right-side img targeted all the images in the .right-side container. I need to be more careful.  Thank you so much again, any tips how you were able to spot that mistake so quick?

Comment: if you needed for immediate element then use ">" in between. Browser Inspector / Browser Web Developer Tools is your friend for css mistakes.